# In Rails 4, how can I get data out of a devise user within a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have an off-the-shelf devise User class, and I have a method that gets a specific user and prints their email address the console

```
def print_email
  user = User.where('id'=>params[:id])
  puts user.email
end
```

However, this gives me an error

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `email' for #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007ff288919808>):
```

To be sure I was getting the right user, I added

```
puts user.to_json
```

This prints the expected json, so the correct User is stored in the user variable, but I simply cannot access the email attribute of the user directly.

How can I do this?

Comment: is the the right code? find should return an User object not ActiveRecord_Relation

Comment: Looks right to me.  Error message doesn't make sense.  You should get a record or blow up trying.

Comment: code looks right, check with the attribute in console. are you able to create and save users perfectly. may be you can post the user model for clarity

Comment: If you use devise, it provides you with `current_user`, I'm sure you are aware of it. Why wouldn't you use this helper as `current_user.email`?

Comment: I actually used .where instead of .find. emaillenin had the correct solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find should return an User object not ActiveRecord_Relation. If it is an ActiveRecord_Relation, use

```
user.first.email
```